# SSE/AVX: How to split a set of 16-bit pixels (packed RGB) into bitplanes

Tags: c, image-processing, simd, sse, avx

I have some basic SSE knowledge and have written some accelerated functions. But this problem has me stumped and I wonder whether there actually is a accelerated SIMD way to handle it.

I have an image that contains 3 color channels. Each color channel is up to 16-bit wide. The data type is always an `uint16_t` but depending on the configured color depth only as subset of bits may be valid. Now I want to split the image into the constituent bit planes.

That means I want a buffer that only contains the first bit of every channel in the pixels. Another buffer that contains the second bit. A buffer that contains the third bit etc.

Essentially in simplified code I have this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>


// img_width is always divisable by 8
// img contains RGB pixels. Each channel is one uint16_t
// where color_depth contains how many bits are valid
// the bitplanes_* are outputs
void extract_bitplanes(
    uint16_t* img,
    uint16_t img_width,
    uint16_t img_height,
    uint8_t color_depth,
    uint8_t** bitplanes_r,
    uint8_t** bitplanes_g,
    uint8_t** bitplanes_b
)
{
    for (uint16_t y = 0; y < img_height; ++y)
    {
        for (uint16_t x = 0; x < img_width; x += 8)
        {
            uint16_t* img_start = img + 3 * (img_width * y + x);

            // Get 8 pixels to use. This is done since 8 pixels
            // means we can create a full byte in the color channel iamge
            uint16_t* p0 = img_start;
            uint16_t r0 = p0[0];
            uint16_t g0 = p0[1];
            uint16_t b0 = p0[2];
            uint16_t* p1 = img_start + 3;
            uint16_t r1 = p1[0];
            uint16_t g1 = p1[1];
            uint16_t b1 = p1[2];
            uint16_t* p2 = img_start + 6;
            uint16_t r2 = p2[0];
            uint16_t g2 = p2[1];
            uint16_t b2 = p2[2];
            uint16_t* p3 = img_start + 9;
            uint16_t r3 = p3[0];
            uint16_t g3 = p3[1];
            uint16_t b3 = p3[2];
            uint16_t* p4 = img_start + 12;
            uint16_t r4 = p4[0];
            uint16_t g4 = p4[1];
            uint16_t b4 = p4[2];
            uint16_t* p5 = img_start + 15;
            uint16_t r5 = p5[0];
            uint16_t g5 = p5[1];
            uint16_t b5 = p5[2];
            uint16_t* p6 = img_start + 18;
            uint16_t r6 = p6[0];
            uint16_t g6 = p6[1];
            uint16_t b6 = p6[2];
            uint16_t* p7 = img_start + 21;
            uint16_t r7 = p7[0];
            uint16_t g7 = p7[1];
            uint16_t b7 = p7[2];

            for (uint8_t c = 0; c < color_depth; ++c) {
                uint32_t plane_offset = (y * img_width + x) / 8; 

                bitplanes_r[c][plane_offset] = (((r0 >> c) & 1) << 0) | (((r1 >> c) & 1) << 1) | (((r2 >> c) & 1) << 2)
                                            | (((r3 >> c) & 1) << 3) | (((r4 >> c) & 1) << 4) | (((r5 >> c) & 1) << 5)
                                            | (((r6 >> c) & 1) << 6) | (((r7 >> c) & 1) << 7);

                bitplanes_g[c][plane_offset] = (((g0 >> c) & 1) << 0) | (((g1 >> c) & 1) << 1) | (((g2 >> c) & 1) << 2)
                                            | (((g3 >> c) & 1) << 3) | (((g4 >> c) & 1) << 4) | (((g5 >> c) & 1) << 5)
                                            | (((g6 >> c) & 1) << 6) | (((g7 >> c) & 1) << 7);
            
                bitplanes_b[c][plane_offset] = (((b0 >> c) & 1) << 0) | (((b1 >> c) & 1) << 1) | (((b2 >> c) & 1) << 2)
                                            | (((b3 >> c) & 1) << 3) | (((b4 >> c) & 1) << 4) | (((b5 >> c) & 1) << 5)
                                            | (((b6 >> c) & 1) << 6) | (((b7 >> c) & 1) << 7);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This does a lot of work which theoretically could be fully parallelized. But I can't seem to figure out how to map this to SIMD intrinsics. Is it possible to accelerate this using intrinsics at all? Or is this problem to specialized?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `pmovmskb`is the usual go-to for extracting a bit from each byte element and packing into a bitmask.  Or `movmskps` to take a bit from each 32-bit element.  If you blend together some unaligned-load results, you can get a vector with 15 or 16 bytes of data from the tops of "green" pixel components, and `pshufb` can put those into the right order.  A sequence of `paddb same,same` + `pmovmskb` can extract chunks of successive bit-planes.  (Blend differently to get the top byte of the other components, and the low bytes.) This requires a lot of shuffle/blend; other strategies might be better

Comment: `uint8_t** bitplanes_r` - pointers to pointers?  Why not a 2D array, or manual 2D indexing in a flat array?  (Or a flat array for each channel).  Might not matter a lot since you'd always want to be accumulating at least 8 contiguous bits from the same bit-plane to store somewhere, but should turn some scalar overhead into just pointer increments in a loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a possiblity as well. They are allocated continuously so I doubt the extra pointer dereference wll matter too much.

Comment: *They are allocated continuously so I doubt the extra pointer dereference wll matter too much.* - extra load-use latency typically sucks, making out-of-order exec work harder.  Adding a loop-invariant constant to stride across bit-planes within the same component should make the inner loop cheaper and maybe use fewer integer registers.

Comment: Another strategy for shuffling to feed `pmovmskb` could be to `pshufb` each 16-byte input vector (or 16-byte halves of a 32-byte load that splits down the middle with AVX2), grouping 2 red high halves, 2 red low halves, etc. (from 12 bytes = 2 pixels) to feed `punpcklwd` from another `pshufb` result on a partially-overlapping unaligned load.  Or perhaps start with `unpcklbw` on two vectors that each start at the start of a 12-byte pair of pixels, *then* do `pshufb`? None of this is great; AVX-512 could do this better with lane-crossing shuffles and test-into-mask, and mask-unpack instructions.

Comment: If you have access to BMI2 instructions, then pext might be useful, though only for 64 bits at a time. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=pext&ig_expand=5120

Comment: @SimonGoater: Yeah, perhaps for grabbing bits out of some `pmovmskb` results if your vector shuffling leaves some gaps, or interleaves two outputs.  (e.g. low and high halves of the same component of a pixel.)